# One to one async communication between services

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to communicate two services in a GCP App Engine project asynchronously. GCP docs states that Pub/Sub may be used to achieve many-to-many asynchronous communication. I was wondering if I could and if it is a good practice to use Pub/Sub for one to one async communication.

I thought I colud have a topic to send requests from the client service to the server service. Prior to send the request, the client would create a new "ephimeral" topic with a random name and supply the topic in the message payload and would pull the topic. The server would publish the reponse to the supplied topic in the payload.

Is that crazy? I not, should the client remove after it receives the response. Will be the latency an stoper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

About the best practice it looks like Google Cloud Recommends to use targeted HTTP requests, this is based on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/communicating-between-services)

About using pub/sub with App Engine, it is also mentioned that this can be done as well, and it will let you achieve communication between apps, but it looks like this could be limited to application modules in the same project as per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq), and in order to achieve low latency you would need to cache the publisher client by initializing it as a global variable. But even with this configuration, it may end up existing a lot of latency as you would be sending 2 pub/sub messages.

I believe that I would use the tradicional http Request, but if you want to try it out, there is a tutorial on how to set up app engine in order to use pub/sub at this other [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages)